Seeking a Sanskrit english translation to a personalized prayer
I don't know if anyone can help me here, so I thought I would ask.
The phonetic language equivalent meaning of the following English words prayer.
Thank You,
Dharma
Om
I am safe |
No harm will come to me |
My body is healing |
My body is sterile with no (intestinal) blockage
The pain will subside |
Om

धन्यवादः। धर्मः ॐ। अहं सुरक्षितः अस्मि।
मम कोऽपि अहितं न भविष्यति।
मम शरीरं स्वास्थ्यम् प्राप्नोति।
मम शरीरं निर्मलम् अस्ति, अवरोधः नास्ति।
वेदना शनैः शनैः अपगच्छति। ॐ।।
DhanyavAdah Dharmah OM | aham surakshitah asmi |
mama kopi ahitam na bhavishyati |
mama sharIram svAsthyam prApnoti |
mama sharIram nirmalam asti, avarodhah nAsti
vedanA shanaih shanaih apagachati | OM ||
Source: ChatGPT Sanskrit

Thank You Hanhara for this gift. I am most grateful. Dharma

Always happy to help. You can upvote and accept the answer.

I share my first interpretation of Sanskrit. I am a self-taught student of the Vedas and an aspirant of knowledge. Thank you, Harihara for the holy words.
Dharma.
DhanyavAdah | Dharmah OM | aham surakshitah asmi | mama kopi ahitam na bhavishyati |
Thank you | Truth God | I well protected I am | my ulcer  is done, (it’s) not in the future |
mama sharIram svAsthyam prApnoti | mama sharIram nirmalam asti, avarodhah nAsti vedanA
my body health | my will atain | my hastening pure being, obstruction is not a sensation (there) |
shanaih shanaih apagachati | OM |
slowly slowly gone away | all that has been, all that is, and all that is yet to be |
